# Script in view not shared by partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a .js page which I am including in my View using the <script> tag. After an ajax call, I am rendering a partial view in the same view. But the partial view was unable to access the methods from the .js file included in the view.

I want to understand why the partial view was unable to access the method.
Also, how much data can be shared between the view and the partial view?

My understanding was, that, since the partial view is like the .ascx, it acts like a component of the view itself and has complete access to everything in the view (Apparently that's not the case).

I was able to resolve the issue by including the same `<script>` tag (used in the view) in my partial view.

Comment: [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) (and do not include scripts in partial views)

Answer (score 0):

you can append tha partial view html block in your parent page using JS. than you will be able to access components.

Comment: I have appended the partial view into a <div> in the view, using $("#elemId").html(response). Still doesn't work.

Comment: add reference of js file in below of the main page.